# how to find mailbox store of users using vbs script-0

Tags: exchange-2007

i have a list of users for which i need to find their mailbox store.. pls help me with a vbscript to get the output.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Not vbscript i know but here's a PowerShell one-liner...

```
Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object Database | ft DisplayName,Database
```